# Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.swarm:wildfly-swarm-plugin:1.0.0.Alpha4:create (default) on project

Tags: wildfly

My pom file looks like below. What else is missing in this pom file?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bbbb</groupId>
    <artifactId>graph</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>graph</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.build.timestamp.format>yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss</maven.build.timestamp.format>

        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
              <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-jaxrs</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.0.Alpha4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0.0.Alpha4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: 1.0.0.Alpha4 is quite in terms of this project. 1.0.0.8.Alpha8 is the current released version. I don't see a `create` goal. Where did you get that goal from?

Answer (score 0):

The WildFly Swarm plugin needs to be defined as:

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-swarm-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha8</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>package</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```